# Get diff (patch-file) that contains differences between local and remote repository

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

I'm using a GIT-repository where I do not have write-privileges on the server. All my changes are committed to the local repository but not pushed to the server (for obvious reasons).

So how can I create a diff (patch) file now which contains the difference between my local repository and the remote one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the `master` branch:

```
$ git diff --no-prefix origin/master > save.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did a single commit since the last time you pulled the repository you can use `git diff HEAD~1`.

If the git repository has changed you need to `git pull` the changes into your local copy and then use the id of your commit with `git diff`.

Comment: You can give two parameters to `git diff`, the starting commit and another one and it will show a diff consisting of all changes between those diffs.